# Where can I get a plug-in for the PHP syntax tooltip help for Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: php, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I use Eclipse Indigo for my development because we use SVN to synchronize our files. I want to be able to get a tooltip of the syntax when I type a PHP function. So what plug-in should I add ?

Comment: What is a PHP syntax tooltip? What has this to do with SVN? What did searching for software showed you and what is your problem to make a selection?

Comment: PDT is the Eclipse plugin for PHP support, but I don't think it's maintained anymore.  It's certainly not up to date and Eclipse removed the "eclipse for PHP" link from the downloads page.  Have you considered another IDE instead such as NetBeans or PHPStorm?  There's no shortage of SVN-supporting IDEs out there, and there's always just using a separate SVN client if you can't find an IDE to your liking.

Comment: Eclipse PDT is an official Eclipse Project which is part of the standard release cycle: http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse menu :
Help > Install new software

In **Work with** select "Indigo (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo)".

In the list, look for "Programming Languages > PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature" or type filter text "php".

Select it and click on next to install it, you'll get a PHP perspective and help syntax.

Comment: I did what you said but after restarting Eclipse then when trying to type a PHP function like `explode(` then there was no tooltip help of its arguments ! So how to get this tooltip arguments help ?

Comment: First, make sure you are in a **PHP Perspective** (Window > Open Perspective, and look for PHP).